# Get previous year start and end date in php

Tags: php, date, date-format

I am able to get previous month start and end date by using the below.

```
echo date("d-m-y",strtotime("first day of -1 month")); //output: 01-09-17
echo date("d-m-y",strtotime("last day of -1 month")); //output: 30-09-17
```

But i am unable to get the start and end date of previous year. The code that i tried is below.

```
echo date("d-m-y",strtotime("first day of -1 year")); //output: 01-10-16
echo date("d-m-y",strtotime("last day of -1 year")); //output: 31-10-16
```

I am getting wrong output. I Need the output as **01-01-16** and **31-12-16.**

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it really simple?
The first and last day of year are known "constants".

```
echo date("01-01-y",strtotime("-1 year")) ."\n";
echo date("31-12-y",strtotime("-1 year"));
```

https://3v4l.org/V0ktv